# Fold out menu when load

Tags: jquery

I have tried to make some JQuery. When you click the button "Animate height", then the box folds out. But if I want to get rid of the buttons, so it will fold out after fx 1 second automatically, how will I do that? I am guessing I have to use onLoad somewhere, or do I need to rewrite the whole code?

Best Regards
Mads

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#box").animate({height: "300px" });
        $("#box").animate({width: "300px" });
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("#box").animate({height: "100px"});
        $("#box").animate({width: "100px" });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn1">Animate height</button>

<button id="btn2">Reset height</button>

<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

SOLUTION WAS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#box").animate({height: "300px"});
        $("#box").animate({width: "300px"});
    }, 100); // the 1000 is the delay in milliseconds
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just set a timeout to trigger the opening animations, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#box").animate({height: "300px",  width: "300px"});
    }, 1000); // the 1000 is the delay in milliseconds
});
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot for the answer. It is working now. As it is now, the box is loading from one corner to the other. What if i wanted the box to load the height vertical and then the width horizontal?

Comment: @MadsKristensen : simply chain your function calls :  `$("#box").animate({height: "300px"}).animate({width: "300px"});`

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot, and thanks to everyone else who helped here :-) best Regards Mads

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:-

`$.animate(action1).delay(n).animate(action2)`

where n is the millis of delay

i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#box").delay(1000).animate({ height: "300px", width: "300px" }).delay(1000).animate({ height: "100px", width: "100px" });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` for your animations, but also, you can use the `transition` css property. **atmd** gave you an example for `setTimeout`, I will give you an example for `transition`. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Taken from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1).